# The rails $RAILS_ENV.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail/) and I don't really understand what this means:

> Action Mailer Configuration for Gmail As Action Mailer now uses the
>   Mail gem, this becomes as simple as adding to your
>   config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

...but I don't have a $RAILS_ENV.rb file. Do I simply add one to my environments directory, and paste in and append the above information?

Now, I've had a bit of a hiatus from rails, and I've forgotten quite a lot :(

Could someone please explain just what happens inside my environments directory? Quite detailed, please. I really don't know what it does at all, so I'd like to know where these parameters are going.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you have three files under config/environments/

1. development.rb
2. production.rb
3. test.rb

you can put these lines with respect to the environment you need these settings for. So that means you can use three type of settings depending on the environment you are using.

Comment: How does the application know when it's in development, or production?

Comment: From `RAILS_ENV` environment variable, usually it defaults to `development` if not present

Comment: Yes, it defaults to development, so you put these lines in development.rb